# Anchor hidden text box ontop of visible text box in html

Tags: html, css, iframe, clickjacking

I'm doing some security testing of a website, and I'm testing specifically for UI redressing that involves an underlying website contained in an iframe with a hidden form on top of the website. The idea is that a hidden textbox would overlay a real textbox in the website (with the goal of a 3rd party obtaining this information). I'm having trouble lining up my hidden objects with the objects that are actually on the web page. Is there some sort of anchoring option in HTML or should I manually include breaks and line it up?

Thank you!

***Edit:** Code below - the opacity at this moment is irrelevant and would be changed once I get them lined up correctly. On the webpage itself are two text boxes with a submit button below them, and I want my text boxes (textbox1 and textbox2) and the submit button to line up with those on the real webpage.

```html
<div style="opacity:0.9; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:99%; height:99%; z-index=2">
  <iframe src="http://website-url-goes-here.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<div style="opacity:0.5; z-index=1">
  <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input text=" " name="textbox1">
    <BR>
    <input text=" " name="textbox2">
    <BR>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can include the code (at least enough for an example) you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: Does your overlayed form need to be responsive, so that it will size differently depending on the screen size it's viewed on?

Comment: It would be helpful if it could, but it's not an immediate requirement for testing.

Comment: I'm no CSS expert, but here's my 2 cents. If you don't need it to be responsive, use pixel placement (i.e. `top: 350px; left: 220px;`) to overlay the text boxes where they need to go. Otherwise, your best bet may be to just copy the whole iframe and disable/hide the other elements on the page.